# Python 3 memcache - append not working

Tags: python, memcached

I'm using this library for communicating with memcache: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python3-memcached

Now everything works fine except for the append() method. It does not throw any errors it just doesn't seem to append anything.

Here is my code (part of it):

```
MEMCACHE = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=1)

saveinterval = 259200  # 3 days

if not MEMCACHE.add('xxxkey', [[item1.1, item1.2]], saveinterval):
    MEMCACHE.append('xxxkey', [item2.1, item2.2], saveinterval)
```

Now when there is nothing stored with my key, it adds the value as intended. As you can see my value is a list of stuff.
But if i want to append another list to that key nothing happens. It does execute the code inside the if but there is nothing actually appended.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here ?

What I'm also wondering is if it did work and there were 2 items to my key afterwards. Would they expire at different times ?

Comment: I am having a hard time getting 'import memcache' to work with this library, is it still called memecache?

Comment: I've since moved to REDIS so I'm not sure but I believe so. What exactly is your problem ?